# Axis position in R scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, position, scatter

I'm trying to create a simple scatter plot in R, where the x-axis range is -10:10, and to re-locate the y axis to the x=0 point. This seems like a fairly basic operation, but I found no way to do that...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Argument to define x axis range is `plot(..., xlim = c(-10, 10))`. See `?par` for more info.

Comment: now why would you want to do this and have an axis and it's labels drawn over your data? This is one of the reasons I hate Excel's plotting - it is just a silly thing to do. A grid behind the data would be far better.

Answer (score 7):

```
x <- runif(50, -10, 10)
y <- runif(50, -10, 10)
plot(x, y, yaxt="n") # don't plot y-axis, see ?par, section xaxt
axis(2, pos=0) # Draw y-axis at 0 line
```

[image: x-axis on 0 line]

But personally I think that you should use `grid()` or [Andrie solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383540/axis-position-in-r-scatterplot/6383813#6383813).

Comment: +1 for answering the question as written. I might suggest `las=1` as well (and maybe `bty="n"`)

Answer (score 3):

Create some data

```
x <- runif(50, -10, 10)
y <- runif(50, -10, 10)
```

In base graphics, you can use the `abline` function to draw lines on a plot.  The trick is to draw a vertical line and horizontal line at the `x=0` and `y=0` positions:

```
plot(x, y)
abline(h=0)
abline(v=0)
```

[image]

An alternative way of achieving a similar result is to use the `ggplot2` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x, y) + geom_vline(xintercept=0) + geom_hline(yintercept=0)
```

[image]

Comment: `abline(h=0, v=0)` is a shorthand. Or even one-liner: `plot(x, y, panel.last=abline(h=0,v=0))`.